# How to programmatically rotate button by 360 Degrees in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

how  the button can be rotated by 360 degree for duration of time 30 sec and after that the button stop rotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 360 rotation animation is only a few lines of code with Core Animation.

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = 
    [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotate.byValue = @(M_PI*2); // Change to - angle for counter clockwise rotation
rotate.duration = 30.0; 

[yourButton.layer addAnimation:rotate 
                        forKey:@"myRotationAnimation"];
```

By using the `byValue` property you are doing a *relative* rotation of 360 degrees to whatever rotation was there before (compared to explicitly specifying the from and to values). This means that the above code will rotate the button 360 degrees even if it is already rotated. All the answers that explicitly specify an end transform are assuming that the button isn't already rotated.

The above example is as small as possible to do just what you asked for ("be rotated by 360 degree for duration of time 30 sec"). If you want to have more control you can optionally make the animation start and/or stop slowly by specifying a timing function

```
rotate.timingFunction = 
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

---

If you haven't already added `QuarzCore.framework` to your project you will need to do so. Also `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the top of your source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
CATransform3D myRotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(Yourbutton.layer.transform, -1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
Yourbutton.layer.transform = myRotationTransform;

CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -1];
animation.duration = 30;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[Yourbutton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"MyAnimation"];
```

Should work as needed! don't forget to include quartz.framework!

Comment: In this case there is no need to not remove the animation upon completion since a 360 rotation is the same as 0 rotation.

Comment: ... "there is no need to **not** remove" = "you could just as well remove" (meaning `removedOnCompletion = YES;` or just remove that line since `YES` is the default.)

Answer (score 0):

Well I just used

Being self.buttonImageView the ImageView you need to rotate.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.buttonImageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.buttonImageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-2* M_PI);
    }];


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [self.map setCenterCoordinate:self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
    self.buttonImageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2* M_PI);
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.30f animations:^{
    btnGallery.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -M_PI);
}];
```

Comment: sorry rushi, i have just edited the code and tested as well. now check this out. adjust the rotation angle according to your requirement.